# How to add and test against a template database in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database, integration-testing

We have a C# project stored in Azure GIT with a Pipeline that currently builds, runs unit tests, verifies quality etc. Currently all our tests run with no database dependency.

We have a template database backup file which can be used for some smoke tests. This is currently only used manually by starting our application against it, but it would be great to automate those tests.

**Is it possible to use this database backup to perform integration tests against on Azure? i.e.:**

- Add the backup file somewhere in Azure
- So that the pipeline could restore the backup file to a server
- Run some integration tests that access this restored database
- Reproduce the same (fetch backup, restore and run tests) locally
  ?

If so, how (in Azure)?

We've struggled a bit trying to make a task in the pipeline restoring backup file, but we can't seem to get the agent to properly restore it (and have a sql server to restore on).

(Yes, we know that unit tests without database dependencies are very preferable, since they are quicker and smaller, but in some situations integrations tests against a reproducable test database would be good...).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Few Question : what is the size of your template db ? Also do you incrementally update your template db with data periodically or it always remains the same with some standard test data.? I believe you want to deploy template DB on Azure for testing but if something fails you want to deploy the same db on a local on-prem SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is **possible**. You can create a docker-compose to do all and call it in your Azure Pipelines and run it locally as well.

Below is an example of how to do it,

The docker-compose starts three containers: **timesheets-api**, **sql-server-database**, and **integration-tests**. The first and third ones are the same image (dotnet/sdk:5.0), timesheets-api to run the API inside the container, and integration-tests to set up and run tests. Both services have a configuration map to host volumes to be used inside the containers. This setting allows the container to use the source code implemented on the host machine.

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  timesheets-api:
    container_name: timesheets-api
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
    environment:
      - ConnectionStrings__TimeSheetContext=Data Source=sql-server-database; Initial Catalog=TimeSheets; User Id=sa; Password=1AvenueCodePassword*
    volumes:
      - ./Timesheets:/api
    working_dir: /api
    depends_on:
      - sql-server-database
    command: "dotnet run"
    ports:
      - "8001:8081"
  sql-server-database:
    container_name: sql-server-database
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: 1AvenueCodePassword*
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
  integration-tests:
    container_name: integration-tests
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
    environment:
      - ConnectionStrings__TimeSheetContext=Data Source=sql-server-database; Initial Catalog=TimeSheets; User Id=sa; Password=1AvenueCodePassword*
    volumes:
      - .:/src
      - ../test:/test
    working_dir: /src
    command:
      [
        "./Scripts/wait-for-it.sh",
        "sql-server-database:1433",
        "--",
        "dotnet",
        "test",
        "../test/Timesheets.Tests.csproj"
      ]
    depends_on:
      - sql-server-database
```

More details can be found in [How to Run Integration Tests Using Docker Compose and .NET 5](https://blog.avenuecode.com/how-to-run-integration-tests-using-docker-compose-and-.net-5) and [dotnet-docker-integration-test github repository](https://github.com/luizhlelis/dotnet-docker-integration-test).

After writing your compose file, you should be testing it locally first and then you can add below task to your `azure-pipeline.yaml`

```
- task: DockerCompose@0
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
    action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
    dockerComposeCommand: 'up'
```